# Open JaCoCo report in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to find dead code on our application by using a code coverage tool (rather a static code analysis tool). I have chosen JaCoCo and am able to get a report thanks to the JaCoCo agent.

I know that Intellij IDEA works with JaCoCo but I couldn't find anyway to import my JaCoCo report into Intellij IDEA.
Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Which edition of IntelliJ are you using? Coverage report is available in Ultimate edition only.

Comment: I do ultimate and I have found the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Found the solution.
I have installed the coverage plugin and the EclEmma plugin (not sure if this one is really necessary...).
Then "Run -> Show Coverage Data..." and pick your Jacoco output file. This file HAS to have the .exec extension, otherwise you can't select it. That was my problem...

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. I'm able to load the file however in IntelliJ it shows 0% for all coverage but in the site report I can see the correct non-zere values. Did you encouter something like this?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem! Will open a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897366/coverage-view-shows-0-0-in-intellij-when-using-jacoco

Comment: Buid source code through IntelliJ before importing jacoco.exec will solve showing 0% coverage problem.

Comment: With newer versions it is located in the "Run" menu.

Answer (score 17):

For everyone being stuck (like me) trying to find the **Show Coverage Data...** action. It's been relocated to the **Run** section.

As you can read in [the official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-code-coverage-results.html#coverage-tool-window) (Version 2020.3), the action can be reached by using the quick search, the various keymaps or by navigating to ***Run > Show Coverage Data...***.

Answer (score -7):

"intellij idea" seems to have no way of showing correct coverage value of jacoco report created. It is indeed misleading and unfair when it shows coverage as 0.0 instead of giving an unsupported format error.

However, as an alternative, we can push jacoco report (created as part of maven build) to the sonar(qube) server using maven-sonar-plugin's target, sonar:sonar

mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://:9000 -Dsonar.projectKey= -Dsonar.branch= -Dsonar.login= -Dsonar.password=

sonar.projectKey and sonar.branch properties value can be retrieved from corresponding project created in sonarqube.