# using JaCoCo maven plugin in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, jacoco-plugin

I've installed the jacoco plugin in my maven project, run `mvn test`

I see that inside the `/target` folder a `jacoco.exec` has been created, but when I open it with IntelliJ IDEA, this is what I see

jacoco in IntelliJ IDEA:
[image: jacoco in IntelliJ IDEA]

and I was expecting this:

[image: Expected this]

Comment: `jacoco.exec` normally is a binary file. how do you open it?

Comment: that's basically my question :-)

Comment: Check out this other stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420621/open-jacoco-report-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open JaCoCo report in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420621/open-jacoco-report-in-intellij-idea)